# Two way ssl in tomcat

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I have an application which is hosted on AWS instance and we used elastic load balancer with AWS SSL certificate. We used tomcat server. As we used AWS SSL certificate we have not configured 443 port on tomcat. Now we want to implement two way SSL certificate. I have searched for the same but most of the information is saying use SSLEnable=true in tomcat's server.xml but this will not work in my case. Can someone please help me in this situation to implement Two way SSL.

Comment: What is "two-way SSL"?

Comment: It means we are allowing specific client request by importing client's certificate in truststore. Other client will get handshake failure error.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i've setup it,

(server.xml)

```
<Connector
    port="8081"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    proxyPort="443"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    proxyName="mydomain.com"
    connectionTimeout="50000"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: can you also give configuration for connector port 8443